# How to change a value in pandas df when itering rows

Tags: python, pandas

```
    counter = 0
    for _ in df.iterrows():
        print(df.loc[df['descrizione'] == alimenti[counter][0]])
        counter += 1
```

I have a dataframe and I want to change a value of a different column ('quantita') in the same row of
        (df.loc[df['descrizione'] == alimenti[counter][0]])

**this is the df**

```
    descrizione famiglia  parte edibile  ... vitamina c vitamina e quantita

    240      Arance   frutta      80  ...         50          0        0
```

[1 rows x 23 columns]

for example when i reach 'descrizione'= Arance i want to change 'quantita' 
something like df['quantita'] = 50  and output like hereunder

```
descrizione famiglia  parte edibile  ... vitamina c vitamina e quantita

    240      Arance   frutta     ...        50          0        50
```

How can I change this value in the df ?

Comment: Please share a sample of your dataframe with expected output.

Comment: I added the df output when printed

Comment: how should the value of `quantita` be set? You want random values or is there any condition or formula?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need manually iterating over rows.

```
df.loc[df['descrizione'] == alimenti[counter][0], 'descrizione'] = 'quantita'`
# or 
df.loc[df['descrizione'] == alimenti[counter][0], 'quantita'] = 50`
```

Comment: i have to change the value of the column 'quantita'

Comment: @AlPan  you can replace that with whatever you want.

Comment: @AlPan  I have made changes